# In Django REST Framework, how to initialize a field value for a createAPIView based on the GET query parameter?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I know how to get the query parameter in View or Serializer by: `request.GET.get(query_param_key)`. I also know we can use it to do sorts of things like filtering the query set for a ListView, but, I just couldn't figure out how it can be used to initialise a field in a CreateView, or any legit place to just keep or hold this information so that it could be used later when POSTing to set the default value for a field.

For example, if the url of the page to create a "product" is: `http://localhost:8000/myapp/create_product/?item_id=1`

The serializer of the "product" has a foreign field "item", which would like to be initialised with item's id = 1 when the above creation page is called with this parameter. Obviously, there isn't any place other than this query parameter that has the information "item_id=1", so either needs a way to initialise the "item" field, or there is a suitable place to hold this information to use it when POSTing. But I don't know how this can be achieved.

The html template for the "create_product" page is a very basic one using render_form:

```html
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% load rest_framework %}

{% block content %}

<form action="{% url 'polls:description_detail_create_from_character' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% render_form serializer %}
    <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, figured this out.

1. Normally, to have a dynamic initial value for a field on GET request, need the "initial" parameter when defining this field assigning to a callable class that cou. So in **serializers.py**, for the field:

```py
character = Field(choices=YourModel.objects.all(), initial=FieldQueryParamObject(param_class=YourModel, param_key_field_name='character_id'))
```

Where the callable class would attempt to take the GET request where we can find the query parameters:

```py
class FieldQueryParamObject(Object):    
    def set_context(self, serializer_field):        
        self.request = serializer_field.context['request']
        self.value = self.request.GET.get(self.param_key_field_name)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.param_class = kwargs['param_class']
        self.param_key_field_name = kwargs['param_key_field_name']

    def __call__(self, **kwargs):
        if hasattr(self, 'value') and self.value: 
            obj = get_object_or_None(self.param_class, id=int(self.value)) 
            if obj:
                return obj
            else:
                raise serializers.ValidationError('Failed to get the object from model %s with id: %s.' % self.param_class.__name__, self.value)
        else:
            return None
```

However, the default get_initial method of DRF's serializer Field doesn't get the context, i.e. obtain any information from the request like get_default. So:

2. A custom field that overrides get_initial method is necessary.
   Find a suitable Field class to inherit and then like this (Note this is an example of inheriting from ChoiceField):

```py
class YourCustomField(rest_framework.fields.ChoiceField):
    def get_initial(self):
        if callable(self.initial):
            if hasattr(self.initial, 'set_context'):
                self.initial.set_context(self)
            return self.initial()
        return self.initial
```

Also change the field declaration to use your custom field:

```py
character = YourCustomField(choices=YourModel.objects.all(), initial=FieldQueryParamObject(param_class=YourModel, param_key_field_name='character_id'))
```

Also, need to make sure the class you inherit would call get_initial at all, for example, HiddenField won't have a chance to call get_initial at all, so make sure do the debugging, testing, and overriding anything where necessary.

These work should get you the query parameter for the initial value of a field.